Correlate CloudTrail EventName with IAM Permission name
I am trying to map CloudTrail EventNames, like "DescribeRegions" to an IAM Permissions, such as ec2:describeregions.  With the event source field, sometimes I can just split the hostname off and append it to the eventname.  For example:
EventSource: 'ec2.amazonaws.com', EventName:  "DescribeRegions"
I could deduce the IAM permission is ec2:DescribeRegions
For other services/eventsources, that trick won't work.  Is there a mapping anywhere, or an API, or just data I'm missing in the CloudTrail that gives me this data?
FWIW, I am only interested for now in "Success", not "Error/Deny" event types.
